# Java Swing: Dialog with expanding / progressive disclosure?

Tags: java, swing, dialog

I've got a dialog in a desktop Java Swing app.

What I want is a classic Windows-style Progressive Disclosure dialog, where pressing a "More Options" button opens up a whole extra batch of options on the dialog.  (Which can then be hidden again by clicking that same button, which now says something like "Hide".)

What's the right way to do this in Swing?

I can't seem to google-up anything directly relating to this, and what I have found boils down to "reset the preferred dimensions to 0 and revalidate" which can't possibly be the right way to do this and also causes all kinds of wacky things to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide/Show can be achieved by removing/adding children to the parent. After every remove/add operation you will have to invoke the parent.revalidate() **and** parent.repaint() to refresh the UI properly.

Comment: Aha!  Removing it from the parent was the step I was missing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a wizard dialog for installing software, or defining configuration options etc. If so, check this: [Creating Wizard Dialogs with Java Swing](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/swing/wizard/) out.

Comment: Wizards switch screens. I think The OP wants something which will hide/show components on the same screen.

Comment: Wizard - This class, including its model and controller, is responsible for the outer JDialog, as well as the Next, Back, and Cancel buttons. It is also contains a large component in the center that uses the AWT CardLayout layout manager to "flip" through multiple wizard panels in the same space. Think of it as the outer shell of the wizard dialog.

Comment: Yeah, I needed to have the dialog be able to "grow" another panel worth of content and then hide it again; all while the original content stayed where it was.